# User/Role List could not be obtained pentaho

Tags: pentaho, jackrabbit

I am installing pentaho 8.1 CE on ubuntu 16.04

have made change of bd from HSQLDB to Mysql, tables have been created, jackrabbit, hibernate and hibernate.
When starting the server, not login, I imagine that the users are missing or not created. ??

the error that throws me in

catalina.out

```
ERROR [CompositeUserRoleListService] User / Role List could not be obtained.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target of Bean was never resolved: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService

    atorg.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.objfac.spring.BeanBuilder$1.invoke(BeanBuilder.java:159)

    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.loadUserByUsername(Unknown Source)

..

..
```

Database Jackrabbit no created tables..

any idea?

Comment: Hi, I think something is not configure correctly. I think you should read and follow 
https://support.pentaho.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/360004675592/Configuring_Pentaho_to_Use_Database-Based_Security.pdf

Comment: Do you have any startup logs from pentaho server?

Comment: How did u solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changing the back-end database, there's a few things you need to make sure you check.

- repository.xml
- quartz.properties
- hibernate-settings.xml
- [your-database].hibernate.cfg.xml
- context.xml (in WEB-INF)

You'll need to confirm the settings for the connection to the new database has been properly configured in all of these different config files. Some additional details on how to config these files for MySQL specifically can be found in the documentation here: https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.1/Setup/Installation/Archive/MySQL_Repository

Past that, make sure that you delete the "repository" directory inside of /pentaho-solutions/system/jackrabbit as this is an index of the repository. If you change your database back-end, then this index needs to be rebuilt. The index is rebuilt automatically if the server sees that "repository" directory doesn't exist at startup.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the same issue on Windows Server 2016 and MySQL8.0, with Pentaho 8.0.2.
Starting Pentaho server from the start-pentaho.bat command, everything was fine.
The problem arise when I was using Tomcat.
The solution was to be sure that Tomcat service was running with the LOCAL SYSTEM account.
If the Tomcat service runs with lower privileges, maybe it can't access to the pentaho-solutions directory and it cannot load the required java beans.

Answer (score 0):

if everything as per the document is configured correctly, then You might be missing the connection change in applicationContext-spring-security-hibernate.properties, please check that.